# Copy data from rows in a table to future rows in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Temp with Date as the Primary Key - one row per day and around 2 years worth of rows. I'd like to copy the CY Actual Volume of 8/1/2017 to 9/1/2017, and so on for the month of Aug (keeping it simple for this question although I want to be able to run this SQL to copy other data also).

So that 9/1/2017 should have 200, and so on for the entire month.

```
Date,  Pipeline,  CY Actual Volume

8/1/2017,      XX,         200

8/2/2017,      YY,        100

.....


9/1/2017,      XX,          0

9/2/2017,  YY,     0
.
.
```

I have the following SQL but it's not working (it does run successfully and gives me the number of rows affected, but nothing changes).

```
update cy
set cy.[CY Actual Volume] = ny.[CY Actual Volume]
from [dbo].[Temp] cy 
left join [dbo].[Temp] ny on dateadd(day, 31, cy.Date) = ny.Date
                          and cy.[Pipeline] = ny.[Pipeline] 
where cy.[CY Actual Volume] = 0 
  and year(ny.Date) = 2017
```

Comment: Do you want to just copy value of "actual volume"(update) or copy the whole rows(insert)?

Comment: I just want to copy the value of actual volume (update). I have existing rows with 0 Actual Volume, so I just want to update those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (myDate DATETIME, pipeline VARCHAR(2), cy INT)
INSERT INTO @temp( myDate, pipeline, cy )VALUES  ( '2017-08-01', 'XX', 200 )
INSERT INTO @temp( myDate, pipeline, cy )VALUES  ( '2017-08-02', 'YY', 100 )

DECLARE @target TABLE (myDate DATETIME, pipeline VARCHAR(2), cy INT)
INSERT INTO @target( myDate, pipeline, cy )VALUES  ( '2017-09-01', 'XX', 0 )
INSERT INTO @target( myDate, pipeline, cy )VALUES  ( '2017-09-02', 'YY', 0 )    

UPDATE @target SET cy = [@temp].cy FROM @temp WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,-1, [@target].myDate) = [@temp].myDate

SELECT * FROM @temp
SELECT * FROM @target
```

Comment: I have thousands of rows that need to be copied, so this can become very difficult using the suggested SQL. In my question, I stated 2 rows just as an example. So here is the what I'm trying to do: My original table has CY Actual Volume numbers from Jan 2017 to Sept 2017. Then it has 0 CY Actual Vol from Sept 2017 to May 2018. I wish to populate these 0 Actual Volume rows with data from the previous months of Jan to Sept. Total rows to be updated could be around 50000.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Volume
(
    Date date not null primary key,
    Pipeline nvarchar(50) not null,
    CY int not null
)

go

--delete Volume;

insert into Volume
    (Date, Pipeline, CY)
VALUES
    ('2017-08-01', 'XX', 200),
    ('2017-08-02', 'YY', 100),
    ('2017-09-01', 'XX', 0),
    ('2017-09-02', 'YY', 0);

update v1
set
    v1.CY = v2.CY
output inserted.Date, inserted.Pipeline, deleted.CY as OldCY, inserted.CY as NewCY 
from
    Volume as v1 inner join Volume as v2
        on (DATEADD(MONTH, -1, v1.Date) = v2.Date and MONTH(v2.Date) = 8 and YEAR(v2.Date) = 2017)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to add that my question stated a sampling of my table. The actual table is around 200K rows and 3 years of data. I have to copy around 6 months of 2017 prior months data into 6 months of 2017/2018 data. So will your SQL still work?

Comment: this script copy data of specific month (8) and specific year (2017) into next month. Script will be changed If you wish implement other case.